# Is reinforcement learning suitable for predicting bias in dice?

Tags: machine-learning

I would like to analyze a problem similar to the following.

<s>Problem:

You will be given N dices.

You will be given a lot of data about each dice (eg surface information, material information, location of the center of gravity … etc).

The features of the dice are randomly generated every game and are fired at the same speed, angle and initial position.

As a result of rolling the dice, you get 1 point if you get 6 and 0 points otherwise.

There are training data of 100000 games. (Dice data and match results)

I would like to learn the rule of selecting only dice whose probability of getting 6 is higher than 1/6.</s>

I apologize for the vague problem statement.
First of all, it is my mistake to assume that "N dice".
The dice may be one by one.

1. One dice with random characteristics are distributed
2. When it rolls, it is recorded whether 6 has come out or not.

It was easy to understand if it was made into the problem that "this [characteristics, result] data is 100,000".

If you get something other than 6, you will get -1 points.
If you get 6, you will get +5 points.

Example:
X: vector of a dice data
f: function I want to know
f: X-> [0, 1]
(if result> 0.5, I pick this dice.)

For example, a dice with a 1/5 chance of getting a 6 gets 4 out of 5 times a non-6, so I wondered if it would be better to give an immediate reward.
Is it good to decide the reward by the number of points after 100000 games?

I have read some general reinforcement learning methods, but there is a concept of state transition. However, there is no state transition in this game. (Each game ends in 1 step, and each game is independent.)

I am a student just learning neural networks from scratch. It helps if you give me a hint. Thank you.

by the way,
I think that the result of this learning can be concluded "It is good to choose the dice whose pips farthest to the center of gravity is 6."

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you do not want to use a regular network? I'm asking to better understand the context of your question

Comment: Thank you for asking. 
I think that in order to use a regular network, it is necessary to have the correct data for back propagation of errors.
But, I do not know if the dice with certain features have a bias of six.
So I do not know how to build training data for regular networks. The data here is just that if you roll a dice with a certain feature, you get 6 (or not).

Comment: For example, as a result of rolling the dice that "6" has a probability of 30%, even if it comes out other than 6, it is the correct action.

Comment: I think that it is good to use NN for the expression of this rule (f) like DQN.
For example, I want to give 1000 rewards to a rule when I get 6000 points and get 1000 points according to a certain rule (f).
But how should we give it? There may be a rule that can earn 1500 points.
Does it mean that the ability to do Experience Replay means that the order is meaningless? (Because it is a Markov process?)
However, this game is one step in the first place and there is no assumptionable state machine that can exist. (A trivial state machine exists)

Comment: maybe I misunderstood the framing. Don't you roll each die 100,000 times? Anyway, you could try a simple network where all your characteristics are features 'in' (scaled of course) and then you have 1 neuron in the output - should I take this die or not, and your 'true y' would be 1 if you rolled a six. I know this isn't exactly the odds of rolling six, but it might still work.

Comment: Regarding the DQN, from my experience DQN fails miserably if you don't have a continuous task, or very clearly defined end states. I never tried your case, which is basically a single state which is always a terminal state - but my gut feeling is that it won't work. I hope this helps, sorry if I don't understand well enough your needs

Comment: Thank you for the great answer.

The only data I have are 100,000 similar but different dice and the results of shaking them each only once.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first talk about Reinforcement-Learning.

Problem setups, in order of increasing generality:

1. **Multi-Armed Bandit** - no state, just actions with unknown rewards
2. **Contextual Bandit** - rewards also depend on some context (state)
3. **Reinforcement Learning (MDP)** - actions can also influence the next state

Common to all of all three is that you want to maximize the sum of rewards over time, and there is an exploration vs exploitation trade-off. You are not just given a large dataset. If you want to know what the best action is, you have to try it a few times and observe the reward. This may cost you some reward you could have earned otherwise.

Of those three, the **Contextual Bandit** is the closest match to your setup, although it doesn't quite match to your goals. It would go like this: Given some properties of the dice (the context), select the best dice from a group of possible choices (the action, e.g. the output from your network), such that you get the highest expected reward. At the same time you are also training your network, so you have to pick bad or unknown properties sometimes to explore them.

However, there are two reasons why it doesn't match:

1. You already have data from several 100000 of games, and seem to be not interested in minimizing the cost of trial and error to acquire more data. You assume this data is representative, so **no exploration** is required.
2. You are only interested in **prediction**. You want classify the dice into "good for rolling 6" vs "bad". This piece of information could be used later to make a **decision** between different choices if you know the **cost** for making a wrong decision. If you are just learning *f()* because you are curious about the property of a dice, then is a pure statistical prediction problem. You don't have to worry about short- or long-term rewards. You don't have to worry about selection or consequences of any actions.

Because of this, you actually only have a **supervised learning** problem. You could still solve it with reinforcement learning because RL is more general. But your RL algorithm would be wasting a lot of time figuring out that it really cannot influence the next state.

### Supervised Learning

Your dice actually behaves like a biased coin, it's a Bernoulli trial with ~1/6 success probability. This is now a standard classification problem: given your features, predict the probability that a dice will lead to a good match result.

It seems that your "match results" can be easily converted in the number of rolls and the number of positive outcomes (rolled a six) with the same dice. If you have a large number of rolls for every dice, you can simply classify this die and use this class (together with the physical properties) as one data point to train your network.

You can do more fancy things if you have fewer rolls but I won't go into that. (If you are interested, have a look at the beta distribution and how the cross-entropy loss works with neural networks.)

Comment: I apologize for the vague problem statement. 
First of all, it is my mistake to assume that "N dice". 
The dice may be one by one.

1. One dice with random characteristics are distributed.
2. When it rolls, it is recorded whether 6 has come out or not.

It was easy to understand if it was made into the problem that "this [characteristics, result] data is 100,000". Also, if you modify the problem as above, it will be added that if you get something other than 6, you will get -1/6 points.

Comment: I also edited upper Question. And, I am understanding your answer. pls wait. thank you.

Comment: It looks like a bandit problem at first glance, but it is rare for dice with the same characteristics to appear again. Even in this case, is this a bandit problem?

Comment: I was a little confused. I calm down.
First of all, what I would like to obtain is a function that tells me if I should roll or not if I enter the dice characteristics. Or, it is a function that outputs how much I should pay for it.

Comment: ***If you get something other than 6, you will get -1 points. If you get 6, you will get +5 points.

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure if I understand the setup you have in mind, but after your edit I have (hopefully) clarified a few things in my answer now.